# How to get PR comment posted in GitHub Enterprise repository

Tags: git, github

According to GitHub [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request), to list the comments posted on GitHub Pull Request we need to put together an URL address:

```
/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/comments
```

There are three arguments to put into this URL: `:owner`, `:repo` and `:pull_number`.

Here is a `curl` command line example that gets a `json` response on one of Pull Requests:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/37signals/sub/issues/2/comments" -v
```

Let's break this URL down...

- The `:owner` here is the `37signals`.
- The `:repo` is `sub`.
- The `:pull_number` is `2`

The Pull Request I am working with is:

```
https://github.prod.mycompany.com/MyTeamName/MyRepoName/pull/3
```

Again, in order to put together GitHub API `URL` address I need the `:owner`, `:repo` and `:pull_number`.

I have tried:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/mycompany/MyRepoName/issues/3/comments -v
```

But it returns an `Not Found` error.

What would be a correct URL to make API request?

Answer (score 0):

With Github Enterprise we are supplied with a number of different API URLs which we can all get authenticating with username/password combo:

```
curl -i https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3 -u my_git_username:@my_password
```

or with Github Auth Token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token 123a42s67f38g45hh67aj89a014sd11fhh444ee1" https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3
```

Regardless what auth method you choose the output of the `curl` query is the same and it is copied/pasted below:

```
{
  "current_user_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user",
  "current_user_authorizations_html_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}",
  "authorizations_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/authorizations",
  "code_search_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "commit_search_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "emails_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/emails",
  "emojis_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/emojis",
  "events_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/events",
  "feeds_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/feeds",
  "followers_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/followers",
  "following_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/following{/target}",
  "gists_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/gists{/gist_id}",
  "hub_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/hub",
  "issue_search_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "issues_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/issues",
  "keys_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/keys",
  "notifications_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/notifications",
  "organization_repositories_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "organization_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/orgs/{org}",
  "public_gists_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/gists/public",
  "rate_limit_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/rate_limit",
  "repository_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/repos/{owner}/{repo}",
  "repository_search_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "starred_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "starred_gists_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/gists/starred",
  "team_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/teams",
  "user_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/users/{user}",
  "user_organizations_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/user/orgs",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"
}
`
```

To query the Pull Request, supply the `curl` query with URL that contains the Pull Request number (`:number`), the repository name (`:repo`) and MyTeamName (`:owner`):

```
curl -u my_git_username:@my_password -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.shadow-cat-preview+json" https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/repos/MyTeamName/MyRepoName/pulls/3
```

or using Github Auth Token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token 123a42s67f38g45hh67aj89a014sd11fhh444ee1" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.shadow-cat-preview+json" https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/repos/MyTeamName/MyRepoName/pulls/3
```